# Can we setup Gitlab webhook in a Gitlab repository to trigger different Jenkins build jobs for different branches?

Tags: gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, webhooks

I'm trying to set up different build jobs in Jenkins for different branches of a Gitlab repository. I'm using Gitlab web hook to trigger the build.

Here are the steps I followed to setup a web hook for Jenkins CI in Gitlab

1. Go to the project
2. Settings --> Integrations
3. Under 'Project Services', I've selected 'Jenkins CI'
4. Now I've checked the 'Active' checkbox
5. Jenkins url : `<jenkins url>`
6. Project Name : `<jobname_on_jenkins>`

and provided credentials.

In Jenkins, I've selected the under 'Build triggers', I've selected

"Build when a change is pushed to GitLab" and provided the branch filters.

Now, In Jenkins, I've created another job with branch filter as different branch name.

Now my question is, How do i setup a web hook in Gitlab to trigger a different Jenkins job when there is a change in a specific branch. I tried providing comma separated job names for the field 'Project Name' in Gitlab web hook for Jenkins CI but it's not allowing comma separated values there.

Other details:

Gitlab version : GitLab Enterprise Edition 10.8.7-ee 075705a

Jenkins version: 2.138.3

Plugins installed on Jenkins : Gitlab, Gitlab webhook

Comment: Why you are not using this from Webhook, Triggers, push event? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/img/webhooks_ssl.png

Comment: dcalap : I'm not sure if I understand your question. If you are talking about Build Triggers like SCM polling, I tried that but it has issues especially when we are checking out more than one SCM. This is because I'm using scripted Pipeline (pulling the Jenkinsfile from a SCM)

Comment: I don't see why you have created another job, why not using just the job with the branches filter and create the webhook by adding this job? In the screenshot I referenced before, you just have to click on Add Webhook and add the job URL, the one that appears in the check _Build when a change is pushed to GitLab. GitLab CI Service URL: http://your-job-url_

Comment: Our requirement is to have one build job per branch hence I'm trying to create a new job for a specific branch. In fact, I've used the branches filter and using webhook for the job that we have already for 'master' branch. Now I need to setup another job which is specific to another branch.

Answer (score 0):

Just use two webhook - in the field branch name specify the name of the branch